# Chrome extension does not work on the first installation

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am learning to how to make a chrome extension and trying to make popup js alert hello when a button is clicked.

background js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request,sender,sendResponse){
if(request.todo=="showPageAction"){
    chrome.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow:true}, function(tabs){
        chrome.pageAction.show(tabs[0].id);
    });
}
});
```

popup.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
$('#btnChange').click(function(){
    chrome.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow:true},function(tabs){
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id,{todo:"clickAll"})})
});

});
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({todo:"showPageAction"});    

  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request,sender,sendResponse) 
  {
     if (request.todo =="clickAll"){
        alert("alert");
  }


 });
```

manifest.json

```
{
"name": "alert",
"version": "1",
"description": "alert ",
"permissions": ["declarativeContent","activeTab","storage","https://*","tabs"],
"options_page": "options.html",
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
},
"content_scripts": [
{
"matches": ["https://*"],
"js": ["content.js", "jquery.js"],
"run_at": "document_start",
"all_frames": true
}
],
"page_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
        "128": "images/img.png"
        }
},
"icons": {
    "128": "images/img.png"
},

"manifest_version": 2
}
```

The code does not work when first time installed and requires refreshing to work. what can I do to make it work on first installation?

Comment: Remove `"run_at": "document_start"` from manifest

Comment: You unconditionally show the page action on all URLs which defeats the purpose of this feature. Use browser_action and remove all pageAction-related code. Actually you won't need the background script at all.

Comment: Ivan Nokonoko// what does removing that line do? can you explain it more in detail?

WOxxOM//I intend to use it on a specific page like gitHub so I will change permission and matches. what should I do if i remove background script? Do i just move the code to content js?